# Integração de sistema C# com dois web services

Tags: c#, web-service

Tenho que criar uma aplicação que faça o papel de um "ponte" entre dois `web service` que armazenam informações. Tenho que pegar a informação de um e mandar para o outro do jeito que esse "outro" quer. Essas requisições e respostas vão ser em base do `SOAP`. Nunca fiz nada do tipo, tenho visto alguns assuntos e exemplos do código `SOAP` mas, ainda carrego muitas dúvidas. Por hora, minha dúvida é que tipo de projeto eu crio no `Visual Studio C#` para suportar esse tipo de criação? O que eu tenho como objetivo (dado pelo chefe) é que essa aplicação rodará como um serviço e será instalada pelo `prompt de comando`. Vi algo sobre `WCF` mas também não corresponde ao que eu quero.

Se ajudar tem essa imagem dos arquivos do projeto:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Obrigada desde já!

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que consegui entender você precisa manipular a informação que vem de um ws antes de entregá-la a um segundo ws.
O que você pode fazer é um windows service comum que recebe o XML do 1º ws e entrega o xml transformado ao segundo.

Para criar o windows service no VS2010 - novo projeto > windows > windows service.

Para manipular o XML procure por xsltransform.

Mas...
Se você tem acesso ao código fonte de um destes ws (ou dos dois o que seria melhor ainda) não há necessidade de criar o serviço. Você poderia construir apenas uma camada de transformação e incluir em um dos dois, de preferência no 2º que receberia o xml da forma como está hoje e ele mesmo traduziria a informação.

Answer (score 0):

Estou levando em conta a seguinte premissa:

Como um serviço por definição é passivo, então a sua aplicação deve consultar o primeiro serviço, o response desta requisição deve servir de base para montar um request para o segundo Webservice.

Este tipo de aplicação normalmente envolve executar alguma operação em intervalos regulares, no seu caso você poderia está consultando o primeiro webservice a cada 90 minutos.

Para este tipo de situação, você tem duas opções, criar um projeto do tipo 'Windows Service' e internamente ter um Timer, ou fazer uma `Console Application` e agendar a execução da mesma pelo `Windows Task Scheduler`.

Eu pessoalmente prefiro a opção mais simples, que é fazer um `Console Application` e confiar o `Windows Task Scheduler`, em todo caso aconselho que você leia este [artigo](http://www.beansoftware.com/ASP.NET-Tutorials/Task-Scheduler-Windows-Service.aspx):

Quanto aos Web Services, verifique se o mesmo expoe o seu schema através de `MEX` ou `WSDL`, se o fizer, então tudo que precisa é adicionar uma `Service Reference` para cada serviço:

> Visual Studio > Project > Add Service Reference ...

Então informe o endereço (URL) com o `schema (MEX ou WSDL)` do serviço, escolha um Namespace de sua preferencia, então o Wizard vai montar um `Proxy` para o `Web Service`.

Comment: Acho que seria legal você explicar também a parte do WebService em si, que, a meu ver, é o centro da dúvida dela.